# python pandas - how to organize plots that are separately generated by a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I write a function to generate a plot for a given value of the variable 'Course'.

The code is:

def plot_course(course):

```
tp = df[df['COURSE'] == course]
g = sns.FacetGrid(tp, hue="SEX",palette="Set1",hue_order=["F", "M"])
g = g.map(sns.distplot, "GRD_PTS_PER_UNIT").add_legend()
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
g.fig.suptitle(course, fontsize=16)
```

And I then run:

plot_course('PSYCH350')

plot_course('ECON101')

plot_course('PHYSICS140')

plot_course('PHYSICS140')

The function works, but they are stacked vertically (like the screenshot), and I don't know how to put these plots into a grid of 2*2, or into one line.

Can someone help? Thank you!

[they are stacked, and I want to organize them, for example, into one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odpxi.png)

Comment: Are you looking for the [`subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) command? [Here are examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html#pylab-examples-subplots-demo), how to arrange subplots.

Comment: no. becase here it's a function. I cannot get the ax of each figure (or I don't know how I can), so I don't know how to use subplot().